# python3 validate elements in CGI.FieldStorage

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic, cgi, http-get

A CGI script gets some GET data like

```
test.cgi?key1=val1&key2=val2
```

The resulting Fieldstorage object looks like

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('key1', 'val1'), MiniFieldStorage('key2', 'val2')], MiniFieldStorage('key3', 'val3')])
```

I have validation lists which are looking like this:

```
validate_list1 = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
validate_list2 = ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z')
validate_list3 = ('m', 'n', 'o', 'p')
```

The GET Parameters can be **up** to 3 key value pairs.

If only one key value pair is returned, i just need to check validate_list1. If Key1 and Key2 are in the CGI From i want to check like this

```
val1 in validate_list1 AND val2 in validate_list2
```

and for 3 CGI Parameters

```
val1 in validate_list1 AND val2 in validate_list2  AND val3 in validate_list3
```

How can I evaluate the GET values from the MiniFieldStorage against the associated validate_lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if a parameter is in the GET request with the `in` keyword:

```
keys = ('key1', 'key2', 'key3')
validate_lists = (('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'), ('m', 'n', 'o', 'p'))

valid = True
for key, valid in keys, validate_lists:
    if key in cgi.FieldStorage():
        if not cgi.FieldStorage()[key].value in valid:
            valid = False
```

Comment: great this helped me to write the solution. I first get the keys form FieldStorage and load the validation_list according to the keys, Then I can iterate throuh the Fieldstroage.